# Smarty assign and display two dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, smarty, smarty3, smarty2

I want to get a two dimensional array's data and display it in a html file using smarty:
The idea is as following: my array contains several arrays everyone contains the category name in the first offset and the attached links to this category

1-file php

```
$categories_links = array();//array that contains some catgories name with the attached links
//some dummy data
$categorie1="Horror movies";
$link11="http://www.movie11.com";
$link12="http://www.movie12.com";
$link13="http://www.movie13.com";
$categories_links[] = array($categorie1, $link11, $link12,$link13);
$categorie2="Action movies";
$link21="http://www.movie21.com";
$link22="http://www.movie22.com";
$categories_links[] = array($categorie2, $link21, $link22);
$smarty->assign('categories_links' , $categories_links );
$smarty->display('file.html');
```

2-file html

```
{foreach key=categorie item=categorie from=$categories_links}
    foreach key=categorie item=categorie from=categorie}
 <!--
  1.display only the first item in every array as the category name
  2.display the rest as the links attached to the above category

//-->
  {/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: You should edit your question and put some sample data in PHP format (not var_dump)

Comment: i added some dummy data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd refactor the data array to use the category name as a key.

```
$categories = array(
  'Horror movies' => array(
    'link1',
    'link2',
    /...
  ),
  'Action movies' => array(
    'link1',
    'link2',
    /...
  ),
);
$smarty->assign("categories", $categories);
```

Then you can use it easily in Smarty

```
{foreach from=$categories key=category item=links}
  Category: {$category}
  {foreach from=$links item=link}
  {$link}
  {/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

It is much easier to use that way.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you use Smarty 3 (you haven't mentioned anything about Smarty 2) you can use the following code:

```
{foreach $categories_links as $categorie}
<p>
    {foreach $categorie as $item}

        {if $item@first}
            <strong>Category name: {$item}</strong><br />
        {else}
            {$item}

        {/if}
    {/foreach}
</p>
{/foreach}
```

Output for this will be:

```
Category name: Horror movies
http://www.movie11.com http://www.movie12.com http://www.movie13.com

Category name: Action movies
http://www.movie21.com http://www.movie22.com
```

**EDIT**

As you mentioned in comment you want solution for Smarty 2 you need to use in you Smarty template file:

```
{foreach key=id item=categorie from=$categories_links}
    <p>
        {foreach item=item from=$categorie name=list}

            {if $smarty.foreach.list.first}
                <strong>Category name: {$item}</strong><br />
            {else}
                {$item}

            {/if}
        {/foreach}
    </p>
{/foreach}
```

This will give you output:

```
Category name: Horror movies
http://www.movie11.com http://www.movie12.com http://www.movie13.com

Category name: Action movies
http://www.movie21.com http://www.movie22.com
```

(exactly the same as the one in Smarty 3)

Comment: Thanks it is a great solution would like to mark it as accepted answer it's only I need a solution for smarty 2.6... my mistake I know since I haven't mentioned the smarty version in my question